# C# path relative to assembly DLL and not EXE

Tags: c#, dll, path, assemblies

I have an app where users can create plugins for my application and drop their dll in a /plugins folder.

The plugin developers will sometimes have to reference files (xml config files, etc) which should be stored in their respective /plugins/plugin_app/ folder.

However, it seems that when they launch my app the relative path is always set to the folder where the EXE is launched (my application). How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they reference the file they can reference after appending the path components:

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(Path.Combine(mainAppDir,"plugins\\plugin_app\\filename.xml"),FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually add the DLL's path to form an absolute path.

For example:

```
string somePath = Path.Combine(typeof(PluginType).Assembly.Location, "Config.xml");
```

Comment: I know this is old but the above example is incorrect. typeof(PluginType).Assembly.Location returns the path of the assembly and not the directory. Should be Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(PluginType).Assembly.Location), "Config.xml")